# увеличить переменную на одну милионную

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт который делает отсчет от 1 до 1500 ну или до бесконечности,  но делает он это только с целыми числами, то-есть 1 потом 2 потом 3.... и так далее...
Задача переделать его так чтобы отсчет был не от единицы, а от 0.0000001 и также увеличивал значение (0.0000001=>0.0000002=>0.0000003=>0.0000001=> )

```js
window.onload = function() {

  function number_to(id, from, to, duration) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    setTimeout(function() {
      var now = (new Date().getTime()) - start;
      var progress = now / duration;
      var result = Math.floor((to - from) * progress + from);
      element.innerHTML = progress < 1 ? result : to;
      if (progress < 1) setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);
    }, 10);
  }
  number_to("example", 1, 1500, 300000);

};
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

как это сделать например на php, или Delphi, знаю, а вот в javascript  полный ноль ((( помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Странноватый вопрос. Может поясните, что именно считает скрипт? Сейчас я вижу простое решение: каждый раз делить результат на 1000000 и будет вам счастье.

Comment: скрипт должен брать переменную из пхп, котора имеет значение например 0.0000231 и каждую секунду, или через определенное время увеличивать ее на 0.0000001...


number_to("example",<?php echo $s?>,1500,300000);

Comment: А кусок кода, в тексте вопроса, вы сами написали или взяли откуда-то?

Comment: @arashvg, вам надо, чтобы `javascript` с машины пользователя каждую секунду дергал скрипт на сервере?

Comment: нет, код на странице в интернете, из базы берется переменная например $s, и увеличичвается на 0.0000001 через каждую секунду, или пол секунды, после чего отображается в браузере в тегах <div id="example"></div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вы увеличиваете на одну десятимиллионную (может это ошибка, просто предупреждаю);
2. Если нужно многократно вызывать функцию через определенные промежутки времени, то стОит пользоваться `setInterval()` вместо `setTimeout()`;
3. У вас в коде `setTimeout(..., 10)` будет вызывать функцию через каждые 10мс. Что-то мне сильно кажется что браузер не сможет выдерживать такие периоды вызова;
4. `arguments.callee` фактически [устарело](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)(по-английски) и не рекомендуется к использованию;

Если не учитывать привязку к реальному времени, получится например так:

```
window.onload = function() {
    function number_to(id, from, to) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id),
            tick,
            result = from;
        tick = setInterval(function() {
            result += 1e-7;
            element.innerHTML = result.toFixed(7);
            if (result >= to) {
                clearInterval(tick);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    number_to("example", 0.0000283);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0dev/93am70br/

Comment: спасибо!!! Самое то!!!!

Comment: не `-7`, а  `1E-6` одна миллионная.

Comment: *Что-то мне сильно кажется что браузер не сможет выдерживать такие периоды вызова;* - вы недооцениваете разработчиков браузеров )

Comment: @Sergiks См. пункт 1 и текст вопроса. Да, заголовок с этим не согласуется

Comment: @Etki Ну конечно, если вычислительной мощи у компьютера достаточно и браузер больше ничем не занят то наверное получится. А так http://jsfiddle.net/0dev/0wak39g3/ стабильных десяток не выдает ни в одном браузере (но у меня ноут старенький)

Comment: @tutankhamun он и не должен ровные десятки выдавать, шедулинг часто себя так ведет. Нам это в общем-то и не надо, пока мы не снимаем показания с датчиков для научной работы.

Comment: @Etki Я не о том. ИМХО ставить интервал 10 почти бессмысленно. Когда ставим 100, а получаем 95-105 - это норма, а когда ставим 10, а получаем 11-20 - зачем ставить 10 (кроме как чтобы изнасиловать браузер)? Причем зачем ставить 0 я понимаю :) (но конечно в таймауте а не в интервале)